# Is placing "var" keyword before every definied variable in Javascript is a good practice?

Tags: javascript, variables, syntax

I always put var keyword before every variable. I'm wondering about it's correctness. Code is working, but is this good practice?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var something = 34;
    var v = $(body).find('p.lol');
    $.ajax({
        success: function(a) {
           var k = a.sdf;
           something = k+0.7;
           ...etc...
```

Comment: That's how javascript work : you define local variables with the var keyword.

Comment: Pretty good explanation of Javascript scope: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope

Comment: @tpeczek: That's backwards. _not_ using `var` will create global variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it is not about coding practice. If you define a variable in a function using
var keyword. it defined locally otherwise, the variable will be defined globally which you can access outside of the function.

```
function test(){
 var message = “hi”; //local variable
 variable = "bye";
}
 test();
 alert(message); //undefined
 alert(variable);//bye
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `var` to define local variables. If omitted the variable will be global or you might accidentally overwrite the value of another variable.

Here's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398766/when-to-use-var-in-javascript).

Answer (score 1):

It's a good practice to always declare your variables (to avoid accidentally polluting the global object), but JavaScript has something called [hoisting](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-javascript-hoisting-explained/).

Basically, it means variables are always scoped to functions (i.e. not inside a loop or other statement block like other languages), so it's a good practice to do all your declarations at the start of each function.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you use it in strict mode, will throw an error. Try it:

```
(function(){
    "use strict";
    try{
        myNum = 0;
    }
    catch(e) {
        alert("Error: " + e);
    }
})();
```

This code will return something like this:

*Error: ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable myNum*

More info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/br230269%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/03/13/its-time-to-start-using-javascript-strict-mode/

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice in that you are clearly defining scope. When you do not use the var keyword you are effectively creating a global variable. Imagine that variable between automatically declared at the top of your file in that instance.

This creates local variables:

```
var someVarA = 23;
var someVarB = 25;
```

This creates global variables automatically (if not declared elsewhere):

```
someVarA = 23;
someVarB = 25;
```

This, however, is the same as placing a var in front of each variable (notice the comma):

```
var someVarA = 23,
    someVarB = 25;
```